# Vim: yank and paste line and maintain column postition

Tags: vim

Background: I am editing a reStructuredText table in vim. I would like to yank a line and paste it. The line only contains cell vertical delimiters (`|`) so this operation corresponds to giving an existing row one more line of space in the source, but doesn't alone affect the output. A simple `yyP` or `yyp`, puts the cursor to column 1 after the operation.

Q: Is there an easy way to "yank and paste a line" and keep the cursor in the same column after the operation as before it?

After I wrote the question, it dawned on me to use a mark, and indeed that works: I can do `mayyP` and then `` `a `` to jump back to the desired column. That's a bit long though. So the question is, can I do this with less keystrokes?

Edit: As Shahbaz rightly points out, I can just write an alias, now I know how to do what I want. I am still interested in any shorter way that uses standard commands, in case I am missing some functionality that I should know about.

Comment: Probably yes (as with everything in vim), but you could also make your own alias for it!

Comment: @Shahbaz: cheers, yes, I may write an alias. I guess I am still asking in case I missed some basic functionality that I should know about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @romainl says, you should `:set nostartofline` (or `:set nosol` for short).  Then, instead of `yyp`, use the `:copy` command:

```
:copy .
:copy -
```

If `:copy` is too long, you can use `:co` or `:t`.  If you do not use any ex commands in between, then you can repeat the command with `@:` and then with `@@`.

```
:help :copy
:help @:
:help @
```

Comment: If you agree that the `nostartofline` option is required (the default is `startofline`), please edit your answer to indicate this and I will accept the answer. (I tried to make the edit myself, but the edit was rejected.)

Comment: Cool! Even without a mapping this is just four keystrokes, `:t.<Enter>`.

Comment: @Rahul Savani:  I edited as you suggested.  Probably I `:set sol!` while testing the previous answer, before testing `:copy`.  @glts:  I understand there are some who `:nnoremap` `;` and `:` to each other, which would make it even easier to type.

Answer (score 2):

```
:set nostartofline
```

See `:help startofline`.

Comment: Interesting option - but this apparently does not affect `P` or `p` (`yy` preserves the cursor position). This option does affect `d`, but a subsequent `P` will put the line back to the start even with `nostartofline` set. Did you have a method other than `yyP` in mind?

Comment: OK, so this option did turn out to be required for my chosen solution namely `copy`, shorthand `co` or `t`. I actually saw `t` mentioned in the help for `startofline` but didn't know what it was. So you gave me half the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could record a simple macro like

```
qamayyP`aq
```

This writes your command to the register `a` and lets you replay it with the command `@a`.